# QMenu.item.selected stylesheet is not working

Tags: python, pyqt, hover, selected, qmenu

I am trying to make the items in a qmenu when hovered to become gray, as with the fusion stylesheet I have applied they become white when hovered. Unfortunately, my stylsheet is not getting applied.
I searched and I found that I should make the "hover" to be as "selected" and I did so, yet no changes.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QMessageBox, QRadioButton, QMainWindow, QLabel, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem,
                             QDesktopWidget, QCheckBox, QPlainTextEdit, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QStackedWidget, QFormLayout, QMenu,
                             QComboBox, QScrollArea, QLineEdit, QGroupBox, QListView, QToolTip, QFileDialog, QTabWidget, QAction, QInputDialog)

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont, QRegExpValidator, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRegExp, QModelIndex

class WindowGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, gui):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(gui)

    def initUI(self, gui): #Initializing basic GUI
        self.setGeometry(QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry())
        self.showMaximized()

        self.setWindowTitle("ScheduleO")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icons/schedule.png")); 

        self.menu = self.menuBar()

        self.SCHMenu = self.menu.addMenu("Schedule")
        self.SCHFormat = QAction("New Schedule Format", self)
        self.SCHApply = QAction("Apply Schedule Format...", self)

        #This is where the issue is
        self.menu.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt; background-color: white; QMenu.item.selected {color: gray}")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")

    userGUI = UserGUI() #It is not shown, but I have it in my code

    windowGUI = WindowGUI(userGUI)
    windowGUI.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Morever, when I tried

```
self.menu.setStyleSheet("QMenu {font: 12pt; background-color: white;}; QMenu.item.selected {color: gray}")
```

The whole stylesheet is not applied

Is there an issue wiht my QMenu selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QMessageBox, QRadioButton, QMainWindow, QLabel, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem,
                             QDesktopWidget, QCheckBox, QPlainTextEdit, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QStackedWidget, QFormLayout, QMenu,
                             QComboBox, QScrollArea, QLineEdit, QGroupBox, QListView, QToolTip, QFileDialog, QTabWidget, QAction, QInputDialog)

from PyQt5.QtGui  import QIcon, QFont, QRegExpValidator, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRegExp, QModelIndex

class WindowGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):     #, gui):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()       #(gui)

    def initUI(self):       #, gui):             #Initializing basic GUI
        self.setGeometry(QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry())
        self.showMaximized()

        self.setWindowTitle("ScheduleO")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png")) #("icons/schedule.png")); 

        self.menu = self.menuBar()

        self.SCHMenu   = self.menu.addMenu("Schedule")
        self.SCHFormat = QAction("New Schedule Format", self)
        self.SCHApply  = QAction("Apply Schedule Format...", self)

        self.SCHApply.setData('option2') #@
        self.SCHMenu.addAction(self.SCHFormat)
        self.SCHMenu.addAction(self.SCHApply)

        #This is where the issue is
#        self.menu.setStyleSheet("font: 12pt; background-color: white; QMenu.item.selected {color: gray}")
#        self.menu.setStyleSheet("QMenu {font: 12pt; background-color: white;}; QMenu.item.selected {color: gray}")        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")

    app.setStyleSheet("""    
        QMenu
        {
            font: 12pt;
            background-color: white;
        }

        QMenu::item:selected
        {
            color: gray;
        }
     """)    

#    userGUI = UserGUI() 
    windowGUI = WindowGUI() # (userGUI)
    windowGUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

The Python string containing the formatting is sent directly to the C++ back-end. This means you have to use the :: (scope resolution) and the : (initialization list) operator. See the documentation for examples:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu

There is also the Qt scope to be aware of, as in where you are applying the stylesheet, and to what types. I think maybe what you were going for was something like this? Picked font size and colors to show a clear difference.

```
self.menu.setStyleSheet(
    """
    QMenu
    {
        font: 18pt;
        background-color: purple;
    }

    QMenu::item:selected
    {
        color: green
    }
    """
    )
```

Full example would look like this.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QDesktopWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class WindowGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setGeometry(QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry())
        self.showMaximized()

        self.setWindowTitle("ScheduleO")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icons/schedule.png"));

        self.menu = self.menuBar()
        self.SCHMenu = self.menu.addMenu("Schedule")
        self.SCHMenu.addAction("New Schedule Format")
        self.SCHMenu.addAction("Apply Schedule Format...")

        # Issue should be fixed.
        self.menu.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QMenu
            {
                font: 18pt;
                background-color: purple;
            }

            QMenu::item:selected
            {
                background-color: green
            }
            """
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")

    windowGUI = WindowGUI()
    windowGUI.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sample picture can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCDId.png (don't have enough reputation to post pictures.